# Chosen working on one select but not other selects

Tags: views, 7

I'm facing a strange problem with the [Chosen](https://drupal.org/project/chosen) module. I've have 3 term-reference fields added to a content-type.

While editing & adding any nodes of this content-type, Chosen UI interface is applied & working with all 3 fields.

Now, I created a view and exposed the filters for all these three term-reference fields. In the view, Chosen UI interface is applied only to one field and not applied to the rest.

In the settings of chosen module (admin/config/user-interface/chosen)
`Apply Chosen to the following elements` is set to `select`

These are the Drupal settings outputed by Drupal into javascript:

```
"chosen":{
  "selector":"select",
  "minimum_single":"20",
  "minimum_multiple":"20",
  "minimum_width":"300",
  "search_contains":true,
  "disable_search":false,
  "disable_search_threshold":"Never Apply",
  "placeholder_text_multiple":"Choose some options",
  "placeholder_text_single":"Choose an option",
  "no_results_text":"No results match",
  "multiple":{
     "field_tags_tid[]":true,
     "field_working_area_tid":false,
     "field_published_in_tid[]":true
  },
  "max_selected_options":{
     "field_tags_tid[]":false,
     "field_working_area_tid":false,
     "field_published_in_tid[]":false
  }
   }
}
```

What might be the problem? How can I rectify it?

**EDIT:** Here is something interesting. When I manually enter `jQuery('select').chosen()` into the browser console, then other two exposed filters (select elements) which were not rendered as Chosen UI elements are now rendered.

Any idea, about what might be wrong with it?

Comment: Just to be sure, are all 3 of your exposed filters using the select widget? Also, do you have any javascript errors on the page?

Comment: @rooby: There are no javascript errors on the page. What do you mean by "exposed filters using the select widget?"

Comment: It's possible to have exposed taxonomy filters that don't use a select field. For the ones that chosen is not working for, are they appearing as normal select fields or some other field. I'm sure this probably isn't the problem I just wanted to check.

Comment: While editing & adding any nodes of this content-type, Chosen UI interface is applied & working with all 3 fields.

Comment: To reiterate what @rooby asked, are the exposed filters using a select (dropdown menu) element or something else i.e. radio buttons or checkboxes? 

Unless you're using a module that overrides them e.g. Better Exposed Filters they will be select elements.

Comment: Another thing to check, is the Chosen module JS file and library being loaded on the page? View source to see if they're listed there. Are you able to manually initialise the plugin yourself by entering `jQuery('select').chosen()` in the console?

Comment: @gigabates: 1. All exposed filters are using `select` (dropdown) widgets. Its just that only one of them is rendered using `Chosen UI`. 2. Chosen module JS&css are being loaded on the page, as I said one of the three exposed filters (select elements) is perfectly rendered as `Chosen UI`.

Comment: @gigabates: Woah!! Here is something interesting. When I manually enter `jQuery('select').chosen()` into the console, then other two select elements are also rendered as `Chosen UI` elements. Any idea, about what might be wrong with it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you have a 'Minimum number of options' setting of 20. I'm guessing the ones that don't display have less than 20 available options. Try setting this to 'always apply' on the Chosen settings form (admin/config/user-interface/chosen).

Comment: I feel like an idiot! I've been struggling with it for almost 10 days now, I've scanned every line of the code from module. Tried with different JQuery versions. But I somehow missed this god damn setting :(